# Not able to Print the folder path in EditBox- MFC

Tags: mfc, folderbrowserdialog

I am using the  following function ..instead of CFolderDialog.. to get the folder path...check my code below....am getting a run time error when i try toprint the folder path name in a edit box..

> void
>   CSelfExtractorUIDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
>   {
>
> CDialog dlg;
>
> HWND hwnd = NULL; LPCTSTR szCurrent =
>   (LPCTSTR)malloc(25*sizeof(TCHAR));
>   szCurrent = NULL; LPTSTR szPath =
>   (LPTSTR)malloc(25*sizeof(TCHAR)); BOOL
>   check =
>   BrowseForFolder(hwnd,szCurrent,szPath);
>   if( check == TRUE) {
>           dlg.SetDlgItemTextW(IDC_EDIT1,szPath);
>   }
>
> }
>
> BOOL BrowseForFolder(HWND hwnd,
>   LPCTSTR szCurrent, LPTSTR szPath)  { 
>   BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 }; LPITEMIDLIST
>   pidl; TCHAR szDisplay[256]; BOOL
>   retval;
>
> //CoInitialize();
>
> bi.hwndOwner      = hwnd;
>   bi.pszDisplayName = szDisplay;
>   bi.lpszTitle      = TEXT("Please
>   choose a folder."); bi.ulFlags
>   = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE; bi.lpfn
>   = BrowseCallbackProc; bi.lParam         = (LPARAM) szCurrent;
>
> pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
>
> if (NULL != pidl) {
>           retval = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, szPath);
>           CoTaskMemFree(pidl); } else {
>           retval = FALSE; }
>
> if (!retval) {
>           szPath[0] = TEXT('\0'); }
>
> CoUninitialize(); return retval;
>
> } static int CALLBACK
>   BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hwnd,UINT
>   uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
>     {
>   // If the BFFM_INITIALIZED message is
>   received // set the path to the start
>   path.
>    switch (uMsg)  { case
>   BFFM_INITIALIZED:  { if (NULL !=
>   lpData)  { SendMessage(hwnd,
>   BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, lpData);  } 
>   }  }
>
> return 0; // The function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25 characters seems a little short for a full path length, I'd use MAX_PATH.

Comment: tanx for ur reply..but I fixed the problem...I used dialog modal for the Edit control..i tried SetdlgItemText(....) instead of dlg.SetdlgItemText..its working gr8

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but it doesn't seem like that problem would cause a run time error.